# Execute event listener only once when clicking on a specific div, but continue executing it on other divs

Tags: javascript, events, listener

I have this loop that goes through 24 divs (boxes) with the same class, with an event listener inside. Each time someone clicks the div (box), it changes background color. The problem is that I am keeping track of how many 'boxes' have been opened, but with my current code even if the box is opened, the openedBox variable keeps increasing each time someone clicks the box.

```
for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++){
  boxes[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#09093F";
    openedBoxes++;
});
```

What I wanted to know is if it's possible to stop the event listener from executing more than once on each div. Or is it easier to just find another way to keep track of opened boxes (for example counting how many boxes have a #09093F background).

PS. I tried adding `this.removeEventListener("click", function(){});` within the event listener, but apparently it doesn't work like that haha.

Comment: The reason `removeEventListener` didn't work is because you actually have to pass the `listener` function to the `removeEventListener` call. So the same function you pass to `addEventListener` has to be used in `removeEventListener`, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `once` option in [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) third parameter.

> `once`: A Boolean indicating that the listener should be invoked at most once after being added. If true, the listener would be automatically removed when invoked.

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // ...
}, {once: true});
```

Comment: I thought this would stop the event listener for all boxes, but now after trying it I understand why it works (the event listener executes on each div separately). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove event listeners:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++){
  var temp = i; // need this because i will = boxes.length when the listener is called
  var listenerFuncPlaceholder = null; // you need to pass the listener to removeEventListener
                           // so a ref to it has to exist outside the listener func
  var listenerFunc = () => {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#09093F";
    openedBoxes++;
    boxes[temp].removeEventListener("click", listenerFuncPlaceholder);
  };
  boxes[i].addEventListener("click", listenerFunc);
  listenerFuncPlaceholder = listenerFunc; // so that it can be removed
}
```

Comment: This is a possibility too, but another user has pointed out a simpler asnwer. Thanks for replying!